# how iMacros can extract the data without having attribute on element?

Tags: extract, imacros, text-extraction

i want to get extract data: name, email, phone, date, city
here the HTML sample code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="grid-row">
            <td>Jimmy Shark</td>
            <td>jshark@gmail.com</td>
            <td>082166883333</td>
            <td>07/13/15, 07:23 AM</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    <tr class="odd grid-row">
            <td>Denny Large</td>
            <td>large.denny@gmail.com</td>
            <td>08575510121</td>
            <td>07/09/16, 11:55 PM</td>
            <td></td>
    </tr>
    <more and repeated>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with the following macro and correct it to meet your goal:

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO

TAG XPATH="//tr[@class='grid-row'][{{!LOOP}}]/td[1]" EXTRACT=TXT
TAG XPATH="//tr[@class='grid-row'][{{!LOOP}}]/td[2]" EXTRACT=TXT
TAG XPATH="//tr[@class='grid-row'][{{!LOOP}}]/td[3]" EXTRACT=TXT
TAG XPATH="//tr[@class='grid-row'][{{!LOOP}}]/td[4]" EXTRACT=TXT
TAG XPATH="//tr[@class='grid-row'][{{!LOOP}}]/td[5]" EXTRACT=TXT
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL

TAG XPATH="//tr[@class='odd grid-row'][{{!LOOP}}]/td[1]" EXTRACT=TXT
TAG XPATH="//tr[@class='odd grid-row'][{{!LOOP}}]/td[2]" EXTRACT=TXT
TAG XPATH="//tr[@class='odd grid-row'][{{!LOOP}}]/td[3]" EXTRACT=TXT
TAG XPATH="//tr[@class='odd grid-row'][{{!LOOP}}]/td[4]" EXTRACT=TXT
TAG XPATH="//tr[@class='odd grid-row'][{{!LOOP}}]/td[5]" EXTRACT=TXT
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
```

Comment: oke work Shugar and i'm done it to save in csv file.. the problem how this macro can run next to page and more page with the link like this  
http://member.googlee.net/afleads?_al_p=0  http://member.googlee.net/afleads?_al_p=1  http://member.googlee.net/afleads?_al_p=2  http://member.googlee.net/afleads?_al_p=.... next next next until finish or can SET until 33 pages... if macros become javasript oke no problem.. thanks Shugar

Comment: You can apply the idea from my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422883/regular-imacros-transform-into-javascript-but-still-not-work) .